# How to redirect to the homepage without going to Title and Login page in Android?

Tags: android, session

I am new to android programming. I am developing a simple app that provides users to book movie tickets. In my manifest file the start activity is title page. When we press enter button it shows login page. After login there will be a homepage which has some functionalities and logout button.

I used sharedpreferences to maintain session. But I got one problem.
After closing the application without logout and after opening the app again, it is showing the title page and after that login page.
But I need to show the homepage without going to the title and login page.  How to do that?

I googled about this and tried so many examples. I couldn't find the answer.
Is this related to manifest start activity or what?

Comment: Can you provide your code in your question for review?

Answer (score 0):

You could put logic that checks for the login status in the title activity, and there your application would decide which activity to load next(loginactivity if not logged in, homescreen if already logged in). Obviously you would also load the homescreen from the login activity after the user has logged in.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple as this. Look at this example. The codes will speak out.

```
if (isLoggedIn()) {
            //user is already logged in!
            gotoHome();

        } else {
            //user is logged out!
            goToTitlePage();
        }
```

**isLoggedIn function**

```
 public boolean isLoggedIn() {
            Boolean mIsLoggedIn = getSharedPreferences("login_status_key",
                    MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("login_status_value"),
                    false);
            return mIsLoggedIn;
        }
```

**Store the login status value when you are logged in successfully.**

```
getSharedPreferences("login_status_key",
                        MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("login_status_value"),
                true).commit();
```

**Edit the login status while you successfully logged out from your app.**

```
getSharedPreferences("login_status_key",
                            MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("login_status_value"),
                    false).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create A SplashScreen for your app and then write the following code:

```
SessionManager session=new SessionManager(Splash.this);
        if(session.isUserLoggedIn()){
            new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    boolean isloggedin=preftandp.getBoolean(Constants.LOGGED_IN false);

                    if(isloggedin)
                    {
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));

                        finish();
                    }else{
                        startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this,LoginActivity.class));

                        finish();
                    }
                }
            });
```

The logic is simple.Sitting on the splash screen you can decide which activity to launch based on Shared Preference values.

Comment: Thank You :) What do you mean by 'preftandp'? And it's showing LoginActivity.this is not an enclosing class. Also can you please explain this line of code: "boolean isloggedin=preftandp.getBoolean(Constants.LOGGED_IN false);" ?

Comment: preftandp is shared preference in which you are storing weather the user is logged in or not.

Comment: Fine. Got it. But showing error that LoginActivity is not an enclosing class. Why is that? What should I do?